# how can i support picture in picture in android 6

Tags: android, picture-in-picture

I have implemented the Picture-in-Picture feature in my project, but I need support for Android 6. Google says it's not supported in Android 6, but I have seen it supported in other applications. Can you help me fix this issue?

Comment: pip is not supported in android 6. it started in android 8

Comment: PiP looks similar to the old youtube app design. I did similar case for one of my clients. If it fits your business requirements, you can use a ```SurfaceView``` to show the video and overlay it over the rest of your project. However it would not work when you move the app in the background.

Answer (score 0):

PiP did not exist until Android 8.  So it is literally impossible to support on Android 6.  It's possible that some OEM made a special library that enabled it on a small set of devices, but if so you'd need to find that library and figure out what models it works on.  There is no way to do it generally in Android 6.  Even the primitives that PiP_ uses didn't exist until Android 7.  See https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/picture-in-picture